# Translating Two Excel COUNTIF Functions into VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function

As always, a pretty basic question. I am trying in Excel VBA to take a the sum of two `countif` functions that are obtaining values in two different ranges with two different criteria, basically whether a date is greater than or less than a particular date.

This `countif` function returns the desired results:
`=COUNTIF(H3:H21,"<12/1/2020")+COUNTIF(H3:H21,">2/1/2022")`

How can it be translated into VBA? I can figure out how to do one of the `countif`s, but getting them combined, even trying to use the `sum` worksheetfunction throws up type mismatch errors.

Any help, as always, is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you double up the quotes in the formulas?

Answer (score 0):

1. add Module
2. define public Function what you want

below my code (maybe it's not you want logic)

```
Public Function countIfBeforeDate(targetRage As Range, xConditionDate As String, Optional afterYear As Long = -1) As Long

    countIfBeforeDate = WorksheetFunction.countIf(targetRage, "<" & xConditionDate)

    If afterYear > 0 And VBA.IsDate(xConditionDate) Then
        Dim cConditionDate As Date
        cConditionDate = VBA.DateAdd("yyyy", afterYear, VBA.CDate(xConditionDate))

        countIfBeforeDate = countIfBeforeDate + WorksheetFunction.countIf(targetRage, ">" & cConditionDate)
    End If

End Function
```

you can use Function in Cell Like

```
=countIfBeforeDate(H3:H21,"2020-01-01",2)
```

Comment: This was a great help! Thank you! While not exactly what I was looking for it led me down the absolute right path! This is what I ended up with and it works.

`Public Function countifdate()

`countifafterdate = `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H40"), `">" & "1-feb-2020")
`countifbeforedate = `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("M2:M40")`, "<=" & "1-aug-2020")